# Get actual record of applied record with SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to be able to get the shipping/billing address from the applied records when doing something like a Customer Refund.

This is the data I see from an applied record:

```
amount = {string} 2.56
apply = {string} T
applydate = {string} 11/6/2018
createdfrom = {object} null
doc = {string} 792
due = {string} 2.56
duedate = {object} null
internalid = {string} 792
line = {string} 1
pymt = {object} null
refnum = {string} 63
sys_id = {string} 4917587510484347
sys_parentid = {string} 4917587510342093
total = {string} 2.56
trantype = {string} CustPymt
type = {string} Payment
```

I initially tried doing this by using the `record.Load` function. The issue is that this function requires passing in the record type, which isn't given clearly in the apply sublist. I initially tried using the `type` field, but as you can see above. The proper type is `record.Type.CUSTOMER_PAYMENT` and here the value just shows as `Payment`. I switched to using the `trantype` and having a mapping function, but I don't have all the possible mappings.

My questions are:

1. Is there an entirely better way of getting the shipping and billing information from the applied record
2. If the answer to 1 is no, is there a way to get the actual record type from the apply sublist?
3. If the answer to 2 is no, is there somewhere to have all possible mappings of `trantype` to `record.Type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lookup of the address values using search.Type.TRANSACTION like below:

```
    var addressValues = search.lookupFields({
        type: search.Type.TRANSACTION,
        id: 792,
        columns: ['shipaddress', 'billaddress']
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Address in NetSuite is different record, linked here. So you have to use search, as described above.